# Best Open Source Visualization Software for Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j

What is the best Open Source visualization software for Neo4J?  By best, I mean:
* Fully featured
* Open Source
* Still being developed/supported for latest Neo4J stable release
* Interactive

I've tried the data browser in Neo4J's web admin, but get the impression there are many other offerings at: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

I've spent some time looking at offerings there, but it looks like many offerings are either no longer supported for the latest Neo4J stable release, are still under development, or are not Open Source.

I've been looking at Neoclipse and Gephi, but:
* Can't tell if Neoclipse is really very widely used
* Don't know how robust graphML export from Gremlin is (the Gephi Neo4J plugin seems oriented towards the older Neo4J v1.5; also Gephi can't display multiple relationships between nodes (though it can count them).

Any shared wisdom would be happily accepted!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2):

[VivaGraphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS) is one available choice. [Max De Marzi](http://maxdemarzi.com/tag/visualization-2/) frequently blogs about visualizing the graphs so see if you can find others.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few open-source visualization software for Neo4j. I recommend :

- Gephi : it allows visualization and SNA. It has a great community (https://gephi.org)
- Cytoscape : it is mostly used for bioinformatics but it is a great
  platform to work with graph data (http://www.cytoscape.org/)

There are less featured alternatives :

- Neovigator : a tool to visually explore graphs
  (https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neovigator)
- Neoclipse : you can view    and edit your data
  (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse)
- D3.js : a data visualization library
- Sigma.js, VivaGraphJS : graph    visualization libraries, both
  compatible with WebGL

The Neo4j website mentions some of the options : http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [Mashed Datatoes](http://mdatato.co.in), a bar chart, pie chart like visualization for Neo4j database.

It uses Movie database for demo. Try selecting "Person" as start label name.